# How to replace distinct values in a column if the value in another column is a duplicate in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to replace distinct values in the 'Grade' column with NA if the values in the 'ID' column are duplicates.

This is my data frame currently:

```
ID            Name            Grade
1001          Mary            10
1002          John            9
1002          John            10
1003          James           12
```

And this is what I want the data frame to look like:

```
ID            Name            Grade
1001          Mary            10
1002          John            NA
1002          John            NA
1003          James           12
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of base R option -

1. Using `duplicated`.

```
df$Grade[duplicated(df$ID) | duplicated(df$ID, fromLast = TRUE)] <- NA
df

#    ID  Name Grade
#1 1001  Mary    10
#2 1002  John    NA
#3 1002  John    NA
#4 1003 James    12
```

2. Using `table`.

```
df$Grade[df$ID %in% names(Filter(function(x) x > 1, table(df$ID)))] <- NA
```

---

You can also use `dplyr` for 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
       mutate(Grade = replace(Grade, duplicated(ID) | 
                              duplicated(ID, fromLast = TRUE), NA))
df
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error using the dyplr method: `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"districtA <- districtA %>% 
  mutate(gender = replace(gender, duplicated(Student Identifier"`

Comment: You seem to have not copied the code correctly as in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Grade = ifelse(n()>1, NA, Grade))

     ID Name  Grade
  <int> <chr> <int>
1  1001 Mary     10
2  1002 John     NA
3  1002 John     NA
4  1003 James    12
```